# How to Write Telegram Schema.tl Parser to Make Java Classes Out of it?

Tags: parsing, telegram

i want to produce java classe (.java) from schema.tl so i can upgrade my oldest codes to latest tel layer (current is 62)

i would so appreciate any help to make this happen
i dont know how to write a working parser for this goal.

Thank you all guys